# Remove 'uploaded' add-in Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I’m preparing some ‘tutorial’ videos and have probably a stupid question that I'm just overlooking the answer.

I’m following the steps on starter:
https://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins?product=word
with the option “Other Tools”

This all works fairly straight forward, ending with adding the generated AddIn to Word Online:

[image: Show Taskpane button in Word Online]

My question is though …. **How do you get rid of the just added Show Taskpane again?**

I can’t imagine it to be very hard, but I just don’t see the option anywhere in Word Online, to clean up again and remove the add-in to get a clean slate for the next video….

Comment: You need to remove the cache, follow the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache

Answer (score 2):

```html
localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear();
```

There is no UI for it unfortunately. You need to clear your local storage. Here is an example for IE, run it on the JavaScript console (F12 tools). Then reload the page with Ctrl + F5.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update here. You can right click the add-in command and select Remove Add-in.

This capability is available for add-ins acquired from the in client Office Store or via App Source.

If an add-in is centrally deployed, in Outlook, you can configure add-ins so a user can right click and remove the add-in if they don't want it.

Comment: Also from a sideloaded add-in? Tonight I was looking at the web-worker PnP sample, that is sideloading in Excel Online. I wasn't able to find any other remove option than clearing the storages from Dev Tools (F12) as descibed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42498495/5793786

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here from google:
If you tested your javascript add-ins locally you can remove those add-ins in MS Word by going File-Options-Trust Center-Trust Center Settings...-Trusted Add-In Catalogs and click 'Clear'.